# How to find math variables in dart equation

Tags: math, dart, flutter, equation

I need to know how to find an unknown variable in dart to solve a math equation. B is the unknown variable and the known is the known variable.

```
double B = 0.0;
double known = 1423.0;
known = B -
    ((B * 0.105 + B * 0.005 + B * 0.055) +
        ((B - (B * 0.105 + B * 0.005 + B * 0.055)) * 0.16));
```

Comment: Why not use paper and pencil?

Comment: you can use math_expressions package to solve this type of equation.
https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any such package to solve equations, but you can simplify the equation itself just like you do in mathematics. Below is such a solution-

```
known = B -
((B * 0.105 + B * 0.005 + B * 0.055) +
    ((B - (B * 0.105 + B * 0.005 + B * 0.055)) * 0.16));

known = B -
    ((B * 0.165) +
        ((B - (B * 0.165)) * 0.16));
known = B -
    ((B * 0.165) +
        ((B * 0.835) * 0.16));
known = B -
    ((B * 0.165) +
        (B * 0.1336));
known = B -
    (B * 0.2986);
known = B * 0.7014;
B= known / 0.7014;
```